# How to temporarily swap <super> and <alt> keys for keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook

I dual run Elementary on a Macbook Pro, but I typically use an external keyboard that has the standard non-Apple layout. I like having the layout (from left to right) <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>super</kbd> - <kbd>alt</kbd> but when I use the keyboard built-in to the laptop <kbd>super</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> are swapped.
I would like it if, when I unplug the external keyboard, the <kbd>super</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> keys get switched in regard to keyboard shortcuts. Does that make sense, and is that doable?